# Search crawls not all pdf content SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search, pdf

Got a strange behavior with some spec sheets: those pdf files placed in a SharePoint 2013 Foundation library are crawled successfully but not all content can be searched in the end. There is an order number inside the files which is significant for searching. But this data can't be searched - no results whereas all the other parts of the pdf can be searched. Searching nearby this order number the results page shows the order no in the further information block of the hit. Opening the original pdf the order number can be marked by the text tool so it seems really to be text. Specially formatted string? Duno. :-/

How to find out whether the SP search or the pdf is guilty of this failure?

Comment: after tested on several systems with foundation and enterprise feature the result for a specific string seems the same in standard search: even if we grant a text layer our string with the format A11.1111-111-A1 cannot be found. Only the closing "A1" is indexed. Last option: Microsoft Call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of research the result is as follows:
This effect

- Appears in SP2013 Foundation and Server which are **not installed** in original language (**english**)
- The error is not a question of pdf text layers
- Seems to appear on a specific text syntax: we evaluate that if a text has a format of LNN.NNNN-NNN-LN with {L = letter, N = number} only a search of the last part of the string delivers a result whereas all other substrings are not indexed
- On an english installed OnPremise the error can easily be resolved with an index reset and a full crawl.